# How do I truncate a string with dynamic length url slug?

Tags: php

On my `slug` column I set the limit is `varchar = 100` and the values will store like this

```
how-do-i-truncate-a-string-with-dynamic-length-url-slug
```

I want the slug will be a `unique` key so I update the `slug` value with last auto increment id and new slug value is :

```
how-do-i-truncate-a-string-with-dynamic-length-url-slug-10
```

So here the `last auto increment` will be a big number at the end..

```
preg_replace('/\s+?(\S+)?$/', '', substr($slugwithautoincrement, 0, 101));
```

With this `preg_replace` it will **remove** my `auto increment number`

Question :

How do I truncate the value fix to 100 characters without remove the last auto increment number?

So result should be :

```
how-do-i-truncate-a-string-with-[....remove from here...]10
```

Comment: Can you truncate the string before the auto increment number is added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't truncate before appending the auto increment value:

```
$slug = explode('-', $slug);

$value = array_pop($slug);

$slug = substr(implode('-', $slug), 0, 99 - strlen($value)) . '-' . $value;
```

Answer (score 1):

Truncate first and then append the auto increment value.

Or do something like this:

```
$maxlength = 30;
$number = 1234567;
$string = "how-do-i-truncate-a-string-with-dynamic-length-url-slug";
$slug = substr($string, 0, $maxlength - strlen($number) - 1)."-".$number;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it:

```
$slug = "how-do-i-truncate-a-string-with-dynamic-length-url-slug-10"
$maxlen = 100;
if (strlen($slug) > $maxlen) {
    $idlen = strlen($slug) - strrpos($slug, '-'); // how long is the "-10" part?
    $id = substr($slug, -$idlen);
    $slug = substr($slug, 0, $maxlen - $idlen).$id;
}
echo $slug;
```

This code can possibly end up with two hyphens before the id if `$maxlen` happens to have specific values. That should not be a problem though.